# Display Image retrieving from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image

This is my code to Insert and display an image in an Image control from DB:

```
try
{
    Byte[] imgbyte = null;
    if (ImageUpload.HasFile && ImageUpload.PostedFile != null)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = ImageUpload.PostedFile;
        imgbyte = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(imgbyte, 0, file.ContentLength);
    }
         if (c.cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                            {
                                c.cn.Open();
                            }

        c.cmd = c.cn.CreateCommand();
        c.cmd.CommandText = "uploadImage";
        c.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        c.cmd.Parameters.Add("@ppr", SqlDbType.Int);
        c.cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagename", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        c.cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagecontent", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        c.cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagebinary", SqlDbType.Image);
        c.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TypeOperation", SqlDbType.Int);

        c.cmd.Parameters["@ppr"].Value = Session["Code"];
        c.cmd.Parameters["@imagename"].Value = ImageUpload.FileName;
        c.cmd.Parameters["@imagecontent"].Value = ImageUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
        c.cmd.Parameters["@imagebinary"].Value = imgbyte;
        c.cmd.Parameters["@TypeOperation"].Value = 0;
        int id = c.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label3.Text = ("id is   <br>" + id);
    Response.Write("Yosh!!!!!!!!!!");
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handlerr.ashx?ppr=" + id ;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (c.cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        c.cn.Close();
    }
}
```

and this is my class .ashx :

```
public class Handlerr : IHttpHandler
{
    Connexion c = new Connexion();
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        //if (context.Request.QueryString["ppr"] != null)
          int  ppr = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ppr"]);
        //else
            //throw new ArgumentException("No param specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream st = DisplayImage(ppr);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int byteseq = st.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        while (byteseq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteseq);
            byteseq = st.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }

    }
    public Stream DisplayImage(int ppr)
    { 
            SqlConnection cc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CVtechConnectionString"].ToString());
        //c.cmd = c.cn.CreateCommand();
        string sql = "Select ImageBinary from ImageStoragee where ImageID=@p_pr ";
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cc);
     cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cm.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@p_pr" , ppr);
        if (c.cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cc.Open(); //
        }
        cm.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
             DataClasses1DataContext context1 = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                var r = (from a in context1.ImageStoragee where a.PPR == ppr select a).First();
                return new MemoryStream(r.ImageBinary.ToArray()); 
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cc.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cc.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem that image is not displayed there is a little Icon as shown in the picture :
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you save the image from the database? Is it valid then? And if you open the ashx from the browser, what does it show? What is the length of the image? If you save it and open it with notepad, what does it show?

Comment: -the image is saved in DB the problem is that it does't appear. i have this icon above  .
the ashx from the browser how can i do that?
-lenghth chages according to the image that i choose.
-and how can i open an image with notpad??
Thank you

Comment: Open the url in the browser like you see it in the html. (So http://localhost/Handlerr.ashx?ppr=123 or something like that)

Comment: http://localhost:7287/cv.aspx  is that what you means???????? because it doesn't display ppr= ...

Comment: Inside your HTML is the img tag created by your code. Take the url from the src attribute and enter it in your browser.

Comment: there is no url in my Image control :
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" /></div>

Comment: One question: if the image has no src attribute, who call the Handlerr handler?

Comment: P.s: On the handler you can use contest.Response.BinaryWrite with the byte array

Answer (score 0):

I know you are not using EF6, but maybe you can compare with one method released on my server and working fine. Check the types...

[image]

```
 public ActionResult GetImageUser(Int64 id_User)
    {
        try
        {
            return File(db.DUser_Image.Find(id_User).file_Data, "image/jpeg", "userimage");
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        {
            return Content("0|Image not found!");
        }
    }

    public ActionResult UploadImageUser(Int64 id_User) 
    {

         ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

        Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Request.InputStream);

        try
        {
            var dUser_Image = db.DUser_Image.Find(id_User);

            dUser_Image.file_Data = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

            var entry = db.Entry(dUser_Image);
            entry.Property(e => e.file_Data).IsModified = true;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return Content("1");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            DUser_Image dUser_Image = new DUser_Image();

            try
            {

            dUser_Image.id_User_Image = id_User;
            dUser_Image.file_Data = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

            db.DUser_Image.Add(dUser_Image);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Content("1");

            }
            catch (Exception) 
            {
                return Content("0");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't  understand your code but I think it is far from being like mine

Comment: @Meryem: he is using MVC and EF, something newer (and probably better in some cases). If you want to stick with your `HttpHandler`, that is okay. HttpHandlers have less overhead then MVC does.